# mongoid NoMethodError (undefined method `all' for Complex:Class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm new to rails... Simple scaffold of a mongoid model is throwing NoMethodError.

class code:

```
class Complex
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name, type: String
end
```

controller code:

```
def index
    @complexes = Complex.all #this is the offending line?
end
```

GEMFILE (extract):

```
...
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
...
```

Comment: Can I see the whole error from console? Here's not enough info to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby (at least >= 1.8.6) `Complex` is a class [defined by the language](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.6/libdoc/complex/rdoc/Complex.html), so when you reference `Complex.all` it looks for the class defined in `complex.c` in the ruby source code instead of your class.

Comment: reserved words... (facepalm)